# Converting std::vector of Vertices stucts to float*

Tags: c++, std

What would be the best way of converting std::vector of Vertices to float*? I have vtx as my original data, which contains two vertices with position, normal and uv and I have std::vector of vertices v with the same position, normal and uv. What I am trying to achieve is getting the same memory layout and data as vtx into vtx2 using std::vector v. I tried copying the memory from v to vtx2 using memcpy but when I print them they are ordered in different way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Vector3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct Vector2
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Vertex
{
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 normal;
    Vector2 uv;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int n = 16;
    float* vtx = new float[n];

    // Vertex 1
    // Position
    vtx[0] = 1.0f;
    vtx[1] = 2.0f;
    vtx[2] = 3.0f;
    // Normal
    vtx[3] = 0.1f;
    vtx[4] = 0.2f;
    vtx[5] = 0.3f;
    // UV
    vtx[6] = 0.0f;
    vtx[7] = 1.0f;

    vtx += 8;

    // Vertex 2
    // Position
    vtx[0] = 4.0f;
    vtx[1] = 5.0f;
    vtx[2] = 6.0f;
    // Normal
    vtx[3] = 0.2f;
    vtx[4] = 0.3f;
    vtx[5] = 0.4f;
    // UV
    vtx[6] = 0.0f;
    vtx[7] = 1.0f;

    vtx += 8;


    for (int i = n; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout << *(vtx + i * -1) << endl;
    }

    vector<Vertex> v;
    Vertex vt;

    // Vertex 1
    // Position
    Vector3 pos1 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    vt.position = pos1;
    // Normal
    Vector3 normal1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
    vt.position = normal1;
    // UV
    Vector2 uv1 = {0.0, 1.0};
    vt.uv = uv1;

    v.push_back(vt);

    // Vertex 2
    // Position
    Vector3 pos2 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
    vt.position = pos2;
    // Normal
    Vector3 normal2 = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
    vt.position = normal2;
    // UV
    Vector2 uv2 = {0.0, 1.0};
    vt.uv = uv2;

    v.push_back(vt);

    float* vtx2 = new float[n];
    memcpy(vtx2, &v[0], v.size() * sizeof(Vertex));

    for (int i = n; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout << *(vtx2 + i * -1) << endl;
    }

    delete[] vtx;
    delete[] vtx2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?   You can access the `data` member to get a pointer to the underlying array, but this is constant and you shouldn't change it directly.

Comment: I have some VBOs where originally I was using float*. I am trying to convert them to std::vector of Vertices instead and preserve the same memory layout.

Comment: *Why* do you want to preserve the memory layout? Usually when you use a standard container, the memory layout isn't your concern.

Comment: @Beta - If he's planning to, for instance, send it to a video card then the memory layout matters even if you're tossing it into a standard container.

Comment: @sabotage3d If you're needing to heavily control buffer layout, then read up on struct packing and alignment and how you can control it with appropriate compiler attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

using namespace std;

struct Vector3
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct Vector2
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Vertex
{
    Vector3 position;
    Vector3 normal;
    Vector2 uv;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int n = 16;
    float* vtx1 = new float[n];
    float* vtx = vtx1;

    cout << offsetof(Vertex, normal) << " " << offsetof(Vertex, uv) << " " << sizeof(Vertex) << "\n";

    // Vertex 1
    // Position
    vtx[0] = 1.0f;
    vtx[1] = 2.0f;
    vtx[2] = 3.0f;
    // Normal
    vtx[3] = 0.1f;
    vtx[4] = 0.2f;
    vtx[5] = 0.3f;
    // UV
    vtx[6] = 0.0f;
    vtx[7] = 1.0f;

    vtx += 8;

    // Vertex 2
    // Position
    vtx[0] = 4.0f;
    vtx[1] = 5.0f;
    vtx[2] = 6.0f;
    // Normal
    vtx[3] = 0.2f;
    vtx[4] = 0.3f;
    vtx[5] = 0.4f;
    // UV
    vtx[6] = 0.0f;
    vtx[7] = 1.0f;

    vtx += 8;


    for (int i = n; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout << *(vtx + i * -1) << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n";

    vector<Vertex> v;
    Vertex vt;

    // Vertex 1
    // Position
    Vector3 pos1 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    vt.position = pos1;
    // Normal
    Vector3 normal1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
    vt.normal = normal1;
    // UV
    Vector2 uv1 = {0.0, 1.0};
    vt.uv = uv1;

    v.push_back(vt);

    // Vertex 2
    // Position
    Vector3 pos2 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
    vt.position = pos2;
    // Normal
    Vector3 normal2 = {0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
    vt.normal = normal2;
    // UV
    Vector2 uv2 = {0.0, 1.0};
    vt.uv = uv2;

    v.push_back(vt);

    float* vtx2 = new float[n];
    vtx = vtx2;
    memcpy(vtx, &v[0], n*sizeof(float));
    vtx += n;

    for (int i = n; i>0; i--)
    {
        cout << *(vtx + i * -1) << endl;
    }

    delete[] vtx1;
    delete[] vtx2;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is some corrected code with .normal instead of .position, it doesn't delete random memory by deleting vtx and the second print loop is fixed to show the data in the array instead of the 16 bytes of memory preceding it. It also prints the struct size  and offsets in the first line. If you don't get `12 24 32` as the first line, your compiler is padding the structs with empty space which is causing your problems. You can use `struct Vertex __attribute__((packed))` to prevent this on GCC or clang. Other compilers have different ways of doing it.

Comment: vtx is shifted by 8 I need to preserve the same layout for vtx2.

Comment: vtx is only shifted because you've added 8 to it twice. The data is still in the same place in memory in either case. You can make them equivalent by putting `vtx2 += 16;` after memcpy.

Comment: @sabotage3d The point @patstew was making is that when you print the contents of `vtx2` it is currently nonsense ... `vtx2` points to the **front** of the array and you are addressing points behind it using `vtx2 + i * -1`

Comment: edited to keep your loop as is but print the actual array - note that you cannot use `delete[]` after adding to a pointer, you need to delete exactly what you get from new.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code:

```
vt.position = normal1
```

should read

```
vt.normal = normal1
```

And similarly for the second vertex in your vector.  Upon fixing that you may find the output matches (it does for me), but it may depend on how your compiler is padding structs.

For example, forcing a different alignment on `Vector3` using `struct Vector3 {...} __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));` will generate "corrupted" output.

Comment: Also the second print loop is printing backwards from vtx2

Comment: I think yo are missing that I am shifting vtx by 8 the question is to get the same layout for vtx2, therefore the printing backwards.

Comment: @sabotage3d The point @patstew was making is that when you print the contents of `vtx2` it is currently nonsense ... `vtx2` points to the **front** of the array and you are addressing points behind it using `vtx2 + i * -1`